# Find minimum distance

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry

I came across this problem in a maths exam. I solved this by taking that a light ray passes in such a way that it takes least path. But as this was a maths exam, i was wondering if it can be solved using maths?

Let $A=(0,1)$ and $B = (1,1)$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Determine the length of
the shortest path from A to B consisting of the line segments AP; PQ and
QB, where P varies on the x-axis between the points $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$ and Q
varies on the line $y = 3$ between the points $(0, 3)$ and $(1, 3)$

Comment: The reflection argument is mathematics, not Physics. One can set it up as a two variable minimization problem, then Lagrange multipliers, but that is a lot uglier.

Comment: @Phani Raj I noticed that you've accepted only one answer out of sete questions you've asked. If you get a satisfying answer to a question, you should accept your favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider A' and B' obtain by reflection i.e. A'=(0,-1), B'=(1,5). Then you consider any path APQB and notice that its length is equal to A'PQB'. But such a length should not be larger than the distance between A' and B' and since the points P and Q that you found give equality, they are the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try using Cauchy Schwarz inequality.